# Apache NiFi MergeRecord Processor throwing Field Eccentricity Error

Tags: apache-nifi

Does anyone know what this error means:  Field eccentricity cannot be null?  I have not yet found information on it.  The Apache NiFi app log does not tell me much either.  Thanks.enter image description here

[When I run the flow, the MergeRecord processor throws the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z77kj.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you defined a schema for this data which requires that field is not null, and a record has a null value for that field, that would cause this error. You should examine the data flowing through your system by listing a queue which contains a failing flowfile, examine the content, and see if the `Eccentricity` field is `null`.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  I had set default values for my columns; I will have to check if they are replacing nulls (thought that happened automatically).

Comment: I created a small input file that produced only 9 splits and tried to merge the splits.  Each split did not have any nulls, and I still got the error.  So the error is being caused by a different problem (but I do not know what is the problem).

Comment: You can try turning on lower-level log output for the `MergeRecord` processor, but I suspect without example input provided here, it will be difficult to help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Ignore, I figured it out.  Hate to say it, but I am working with the UCS satellite database as input - it has 36 fields - Eccentricity is one of the fields.  I forgot to add a default value for this field for handling nulls.  Thanks for trying to answer my question Andy.